# GCP Cloud Build: No longer able to build latest commits

Tags: bitbucket, google-cloud-build

We use Bitbucket for our source
We use GCP Cloud Build for building and deploying
Since last couple of days, auto-trigger is not working as in it doesn't start the build
If I manually trigger it, it pick the last commit it successfully built and deployed

Trigger is set to "Push To Branch" with filter of branch name, one for develop and other for master

I think it could be because we migrated our domain and Google cloud build no longer has access to repository? But then how come it keeps working on last commit?

Comment: Hi! Could you add to your question the output of `gcloud beta builds triggers <TRIGGER>`? Be aware to exclude sensible data.

Comment: I finally figured out what was happening. The user that was used to authenticate connection to external repository in google cloud repository was removed from bitbucket.

To fix it, I had to disconnect the repository (I was afraid I would have to setup triggers and everything else again) and reconnect while I was logged into Bitbucket.

It used my credentials and preserved all other previous configurations which was great!

I didn't find any other way to change credentials.

Comment: Please, consider adding an answer with your findings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was happening. The user that was used to authenticate connection to external repository in google cloud repository was removed from bitbucket. To fix it, I had to disconnect the repository (I was afraid I would have to setup triggers and everything else again) and reconnect while I was logged into Bitbucket. It used my credentials and preserved all other previous configurations which was great! I didn't find any other way to change credentials.